# check if current url/page equals checkout page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I try to **hide** the "cash on pickup"-payment-gateway [cop] when I am on the checkout page of my woocommerce installation. When I echo the code it gets two times executed. 
One time correctly,
the other time it truncates the end of the url:

functions.php

```
// Disable gateway on checkout page
function payment_gateway_disable_cash_on_delivery_on_checkout( $available_gateways ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    global $wp;

    // Helper
    echo(" || get_page_link: ");
    echo(get_page_link());
    echo(" || wp->request: ");
    echo(home_url( $wp->request));
    echo(" || get_checkout_url: ");
    echo($woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url());
    echo(" || end. ");

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cop'] ) && (get_page_link() == $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url())) {
        unset(  $available_gateways['cop'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_cash_on_delivery_on_checkout' );
```

Output on the checkout page

```
  || get_page_link: https://mypage.com/en/checkout/ 
  || wp->request: https://mypage.com/en/checkout/ 
  || get_checkout_url: https://mypage.com/en/checkout/ || end.
  || get_page_link: https://mypage.com/en/ 
  || wp->request: https://mypage.com/en/
  || get_checkout_url: https://mypage.com/en/checkout/ || end.
```

The 
Why this happens, or how to solve that?

Here a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can't you just disable the payment gateway from setting?

Comment: yes, done, refreshed: Still the exact same output. I added an image to my post, the weired thing is, that on the top of the page it shows it exactly correct. and above the payments its wrong.

Comment: I have also to mention that in the first loading the "cash-on-delivery" option ("Barzahlung bei Übergabe") is hidden while the spinning wheel is present, after the page is loaded completely it "appears" magically. So the method is called TWICE

Comment: ok. I tried it now by including `wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );`. This is because an ajax request will made, which changes the url and the button reappears.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in this posts's title, you don't need to check for the page's URL to see if you're on the checkout page as Woocommerce has a conditional for that - [`is_checkout()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_checkout.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

I had to disable the woocommerce checkout ajax script. It's causing a reload and adds some parameters which changes the url. This causes the fail of my equal.

```
/* hide payment method "cash on delivery on cart view (it should only available in POS) */

// Disable gateway on checkout page
function payment_gateway_disable_cash_on_delivery_on_checkout( $available_gateways ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    // we need to dequeue the checkout script, otherwise the ajax call will change our url and the cop option is shown
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cop'] ) && (get_page_link() == $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url())) {
        unset(  $available_gateways['cop'] );
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_cash_on_delivery_on_checkout' );
```